# refreshing of canvas is happening only after touch

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using ViewPagerparallax class,(for parallax view ) and I am setting the background using `pager.setbackgroundAsset(....);`

everything works fine....but I have a situation,what i want to achieve is that whenever the fragments go in a pause state and whenever it is resumed,the background should change and hence i am changing the background in the onResume method but seems like change is only visible whenever i try to swipe between fragments ...

this is my code

```
public void onResume()
    {   

        Activity_Fragments ab = (Activity_Fragments) this.getActivity();
        ViewPagerParallax pager=ab.hi();
         int arr[]={R.raw.a1,R.raw.a2,R.raw.a3,R.raw.a4,R.raw.a5,R.raw.a6,R.raw.a7,R.raw.a8,
                    R.raw.a9,R.raw.a10,R.raw.a11,R.raw.a12,R.raw.a13,R.raw.a14,R.raw.a15,R.raw.a16,
                    R.raw.a17,R.raw.a18,R.raw.a19,R.raw.a20,R.raw.a21,R.raw.a22,R.raw.a23,
                    R.raw.a24,R.raw.a25,R.raw.a26,R.raw.a27,R.raw.a28,R.raw.a29};
            int x=(int)(Math.random() * ((28 ) + 1));
            pager.setBackgroundAsset(arr[x]);
```

Answer (score 1):

A few notes.

First of, I am assuming you are using this: https://github.com/MatthieuLJ/ViewPagerParallax/blob/master/src/com/matthieu/ViewPagerParallax.java

When looking at the source it appears to be that you are doing things correctly.

I few things I can see that could be happening

1. The max number of pages set is 0, which is the default
2. The width or height is 0
3. The background hasn't changed from last time
4. The application has run out of memory (They say they don't want to use more then 1/5th of the memory
5. An exception was thrown while creating the bitmap of the image

A few things you could try

For point number 1, if you haven't already, call the `set_max_pages` with a number you see fit.

Point 2, Is the ViewPager in the activity with width and height set?

Point 3, confirm that you generator is working. (Already done, logic works perfect)

```
int arr[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,
           18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29};
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    Log.d("TEST", String.valueOf(arr[(int)(Math.random() * ((28 ) + 1))]));
}
```

This returns the desired output, no problem there.

Point 4 & 5, Check logcat, it could say some errors, the tag should say `ViewPagerParallax`

I would say point 1 could be it, it will draw the background if it hasn't already once you set it.

Comment: nope,it isn't an error,I am guessing is it a canvas thing ?

Comment: It appears to be changing every time on my device (Galaxy S4). When do you expect for the background to change? Very nice UI btw.

Comment: thank you :) it is still a work in progress,need to do alot of things.
when does it change exactly ?in my phone ,it only changes when i touch it ..i mean see ..i press home screen,then i come back,it should change automatically right ?but it doesn't,it only changes when i start swiping to the next fragment

Comment: By what you have posted I would expect for the background to only move when you change pages, and change completely to a new background picture when you go to a new activity, or the activity is no longer visible on the screen and then you return to that activity by pressing back, or opening it from the recent apps screen. I would expect that it would start the activity again (onCreate will be called, therefore the default image) if you open it from the app icon. When I turned my screen off and back on it triggered the image change, as expected.

Comment: wait wait i think i wasn't clear enough.....
or maybe it is working as expected ,because we are not on the same track.I don't want/expect  the wallpaper to change when swapping b/w fragments,and it doesn't happen and this part works as expected 

Now I am telling you what i am doing,I open the app,that song list appears with a background,now i press home screen,then  i come back,but the wallpaper remains the same(should have changed by now),and it  changes suddenly  when i touch the screen or start dragging/swiping b/w pages

Comment: i am guessing it is a device issue ,because the image is changing without any user interaction on your phone ,but it doesn't on my phone

Comment: Yeah, I understand what you want. I got that. 

I think it's is a difference in devices. On mine no matter what it is different every time I come back to the app. Are you using the emulator? The device you are using may use some kind of caching, when you put your finger on the screen it may cause a redraw. You can see the redraws if you enable the `Show GPU overdraw`, `Show DPU view updates` or `Show screen updates` in the developer settings. Sorry I can't give you a definitive answer, but I believe it is a device issue.

Comment: I am using a sony phone and i didn't understand the view draws thing,it is not in my developer options/or maybe it is with a different name

Comment: It may not be available for you device version, I am running Android 4.3, I don't believe it was available till Android 4.0

Comment: have you enabled "destroy all activities when the user leaves it" lol because then it  will work as expected...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure how setBackgroundAsset works, but try a call to invalidate(); at the end of onResume(). That will insure that your onDraw() method will be called ASAP and the new background will be redrawn.